# How to not label the origin using tkz-base for decimal xmin/ymin between -1 and 0?

Tags: tkz-base

I want to plot a grid with axes for `\tkzInit[xmin=-2.2,xmax=2.2,ymin=-0.2,ymax=4]`

To not plot the origin, one can do:

```
\tkzLabelX[orig=false] \tkzLabelY[orig=false]
\tkzDrawXY
```

This works perfectly fine, as long as in `\tkzInit`, xmin respectively ymin are either exactly 0 or smaller than -1. However, when choosing a decimal between -1 and 0, the origin label gets drawn anyways. For `ymin=-1.2`, it works perfectly fine again. It works like that for both axes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-2.2,ymin=-1.2,xmax=2,ymax=4]
  \tkzLabelX[orig=false] \tkzLabelY[orig=false]
  \tkzDrawXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy fix to not draw it?

Comment: I was still unable to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to find an easy solution but I can try ... I need to modify a lot of codes.
You can avoid the problem with something like that :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-2.2,xmax=2.2,ymin=0,ymax=4]
    \tkzLabelX[orig=false] \tkzLabelY[orig=false]
      \tkzDrawXY
      \draw (0,-0.2) to (0,0); % little piece of tikz's code
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply!

I tried to keep my example minimal. In practise im using a grid as well, so redrawing the axe would not be enough, I would have to redraw the entire grid/subgrid below the axis.

Comment: @Shakaja Another solution is to create with `Tikz` a macro to label the axe.